# Crop an Image in irregular shape

Tags: java, android, crop

I need to crop an Image in irregular shape my app, i.e., I select a portion by finger and if I click crop button, the selected portion alone in the Image will be saved in SDCard.

How to achieve it?

Comment: even am looking for the same thing.... But i can suggest u something. Get the points that are the boundaries of the image to be cropped and replace the remaining part of the image as transparent . Not sure how to work on this. But just got an idea that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a Path for the Shape you want to be cut out.
Then create a rectangle around it an set everything between your shape an the rectangle to transparent (Alpha Channel)

This source here should give you some hints:
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/blob/develop/src/com/android/camera/CropImage.java

Take a look at the onSaveClicked method, line 209

Comment: I can't Implement this link :( please give me another way to do ... Thanks in advance

Comment: the link doesn't work any more, could some one give a source code example?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this project:
https://github.com/coderush/FlexiCrop

It has the code to crop irregular shapes.

Comment: while this might answer the question, it is recommended to put context & more details in the post. Link only answers are discouraged in StackOverflow.